why forge init --force not producing the lib folder?
Steps Taken (Method 1):
git clone git@github.com:t4sk/hello-foundry.git

npm i

forge build

In this method, the lib folder was already present as part of the project. The forge build command worked as expected.
Steps Taken (Method 2):
curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash

foundryup

However, when using this approach (foundryup) to initialize Foundry, the lib folder is not being created automatically.
Solution:
forge install foundry-rs/forge-std

Question:
But, my question is why it is not created automatically when I run forge init. Is there anything missing in the root bash folder?


There maybe a issue with the global configuration of foundryup on your laptop.
Also check whether your foundry.toml file contains this line libs = ["lib"].
If global configuration is the issue just run:
foundryup --clean
then
foundryup
